# How can I create simple search using array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, search

I'd like to create search using arrays, not database. Am i doing this right?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#sample', function() {
      var inputs = document.getElementById("key_id").value;
      var keys = ("testing", "test", "service");
      var keyslgt = keys.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < keyslgt; i++) {
        if (inputs == keys[i]) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Success";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Try different keywords";
        }
      }
      return false;
    });
  });

</script>
```

I want the inputs to search through the array; if the it matches its success(example). I'm avoiding php because i dont want my page to reload. I tried to use ajax codes for the page to not reload upon click of the submit button, but its not working so im trying other ways.

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue with this loop as if the last key is not a match it will always say 'Try different keywords' even in an earlier word was a match.
You also have syntax issues. that should be debugged before posting as they will be obvious in the dev console.

```
for(var i=0; i < keyslgt; i++){
  if (inputs == keys[i]){
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Success";
     // you could break here to prevent the false condition being met
     break;
  }
  else{
    // this will always show in your code unless the last key matches the input
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Try different keywords";
  }
}
```

Comment: so i just need to add `break;` ?, could you tell me wheres my syntax issue as i am really not an expert on programming. thanks